# How to sync sprites on an infinite terrain?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have an infinite terrain generator and wanted to make a water sprite (moving water) to add some detail to the map. Terrain is devided into chunks and when I load new water chunks, the water sprite is not synced with old chunks.

So, my question is: How can I make sure all my water sprites are synced (same frame and same time of changing to a new frame), even when I load the new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change them all yourself by adding an `enterFrame` listener to the Runtime. Each frame the listener function is called, you can use the sprite `setFrame()` to update the appearance of each sprite.  This approach should not necessary be more costly than Corona's convenience methods for playing sequences of frames.

It is important that all those water sprites use the same image sheet for their frames to save space in texture memory.  Also, I understand that your map is huge/infinite, you really only need to update the frame in ** on screen** sprites.  As the player moves around the map and different grid squares need to move into view, you set the frame on those sprites to whatever it needs to be to fit with whatever was already on screen at the end of the previous frame.

Comment: But what if I have hundreds of water tiles at all times? Won't it decrease the performance?

Comment: Maybe.  You'd have to try it out.  I think the fact that all the water sprites are using the same textures (sprite sheet) will help.

Comment: @FICHEKK I've added an important paragraph to my answer to address some of your cost concerns.

Comment: With some tweaking, this worked very nicely.
Thank you so much!